# SpringBoot - Log4J2 - Redirect Standard Out to log4j2 Pattern

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, logback, slf4j

I am trying to redirect the Spring Boot logs to log4j2 but I don't see what I am missing with the configuration.

Notice between A and B, in the Picture 1 below, how the status logs contain some of log entries in my desired pattern but some do not.

In the picture "MYCONFIG > " is a temporary prefix for testing in my pattern.

What I am after is to customize the format of the logs after Spring Boot starts.

Picture 1 - Console Output:

[image: Console Output]

Picture 2 - log4j2.properties File

[image: log4j2.properties]

What I have looked at so far is this:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

My test log output shows up in the Spring Boot output through slf4j but not in my desired pattern.

Thanks in advance,
Erion

Comment: `log4j2-spring.xml`. Also note you can use `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` to customise the logging pattern. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml

Comment: Thanks, that could be a possible way to set it globally.

My hunch is that Logback is printing these and it is simply redirecting to the console output without going through the log4j2 processing. I might have something missing in my dependency management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to indirectly solve this issue by simply upgrading to a more recent version of Spring Boot, 2.5.3.

As part of this I also had to add a direct dependency to the spring-boot-starter-validation library since it is not included as part of spring-boot-starter-web anymore.

[image]